# Dynamic(database values) Admin prefix url laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, dynamic-url

```
Hi i m laravel fresher so i don't know How to set backend url dynamic
```

like
 **https://sample.com/admin**
   to
 **https://sample.com/somename**

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>'admin','middleware' => 'Admin_kernal'], function ()
```

`{ 
   //code here
 }
Thanking you.....`

Answer (score 1):

Read about [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters). Set the route:

```
Route::get('{name}', 'SomeController@handle');
```

And in the `handle()` method of `SomeController`:

```
public function handle($name) {
    echo $name;
    ....
}
```